# JAXB Unmarshalling - pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am working on a simple utility that validates what developers add to the pom.xml. For example, there could be a restriction that all dependency versions MUST be managed by a parent pom and if a developer adds a version tag to a dependency in one of the child projects, then the utility should catch that. For this, I am trying to load the contents of the pom.xml into the maven model class "org.apache.maven.model.Model". However, I am getting this exception:

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0", local:"project"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Adding a custom validation handler to ignore "unexpected element" exceptions (in fact, return true always) did not work. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        unmarshalXMLToObject(new File("pom.xml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}


public static Model unmarshalXMLToObject(File xmlFileToUnmarshal) throws JAXBException, SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Model.class);

    Unmarshaller m = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    m.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent arg0) {
            // return true always
            return true;
        }
    });

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Model objectToReturn = (Model) m.unmarshal(xmlFileToUnmarshal);

    return objectToReturn;
}
```

I also tried adding the maven-4.0.0.xsd to the unmarshaller but that did not help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that I did not need to use JAXB unmarshalling at all.

The following piece of code did the trick, at least for what I wanted.

```
org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader mavenreader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

org.apache.maven.model.Model model = mavenreader.read(new FileReader(pomXml));
```

With that I had the complete maven pom.xml as a java class.

I guess the presence of JAXB in the title and the tags turned away potential answerers from this question.